# How can I add space between the table of contents and the YAML title?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

A basic R markdown script:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Example example"
output: 
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
    toc: true
    number_sections: true
---

# ALPHA Header

## Alpha sub-1

## Alpha sub-2

## Alpha sub-3
```

Will generate something akin to this:

[image]

I'd like to pad the space between the YAML headers and the table of contents - but I'm not sure how. I can specify CSS selector and styles but this only applies to Markdown after the auto generated ToC.

Comment: Just add HTML line breaks within the author field: `author: "Example example<br><br>"`

Comment: @MartinSchmelzer That worked perfectly, thanks. Feel free to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add HTML line breaks in your author or title fields:

```
author: "Example example<br><br>"
```

Or a div with a certain height:

```
author: "Example example<div style=\"height: 100px;\"></div>"
```